# CSS3 not transitioning out

Tags: css, effects, transition, out

I'm having a bit of a problem with one particular CSS3 transition ([here](http://ember.lukeseager.com))

The video 'slider' type thing...when you hover over one of the titles the video embed pops up, great! But it doesn't slide back down! And I have no idea why! It's built off of [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/thumbslider/#comment-64227) article (altered for video and a wordpress loop).

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="empty">
<!--IMG link here for background image-->
</div>

<?php $currentID = get_the_ID();
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
  'cat' => 5,
  'posts_per_page' => 4, 
  'post__not_in' => array($currentID) 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="related">
    <div class="each">
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br>
   <p><?php getCustomField('vid-intro'); ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="home_video">
<div class="video">
    <?php getCustomField('embed_url'); ?>
</div>
</div>  
</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>                      
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#slider { max-width: 942px; height: 360px; margin: 2em auto 1em auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1em #999; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }

a .home_video { 
width: 642px; 
height: 360px; 
position: absolute;
top: 360px;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
-moz-transition: top .5s ease;
-o-transition: top .5s ease;
-ms-transition: top .5s ease;
transition: top .5s ease;
}

a:hover .home_video {
top: 0px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

I've tried many different variations of where to put the transition, and how to name the .home_video div (with or without the a tag) and tried putting the transition on both the hover and non-hover state but can't seem to get it to transition back, even though all of my other CSS3 effects do.

Any ideas guys? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
-webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
-moz-transition: top .5s ease;
-o-transition: top .5s ease;
-ms-transition: top .5s ease;
transition: top .5s ease;
```

to this:

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
```

Hope it will help...